# What do I do about getters when using Composite design pattern?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

The actual implementation might be over kill for Javascript, but I wanted to write a new `Element` class and an `ElementList` class to get a better idea how the Composite design patter works.  For simplicity suppose I have the following for my `Element` class:

```
Element = function(nativeElement) {
    this.element = nativeElement;
}
Element.prototype = {
    addClass: function(classString) {...},
    clone: function(deep) {...},
    getHtml: function() {...},
    getId: function() {...},
    getNativeElement: function() {...},
    getStyle: function(style) {...},
    hasClass: function(classString) {...},
    removeClass: function(classString) {...},
    setHtml: function(html) {...},
    setId: function(id) {...},
    setStyle: function(style, value) {...}
}
```

My first idea was to only implement the methods that make sense for a Composite:

```
ElementList.prototype = {
    addClass: function(classString) {...},
    clone: function(deep) {...},
    hasClass: function(classString) {...},
    removeClass: function(classString) {...},
    setHtml: function(html) {...},
    setStyle: function(style, value) {...}
}
```

But what then interfaces does each class implement?  I know JS doesn't have interfaces, but for the exercise, let's suppose it does. The `ElementList` class will need to be able to work with either `Element`s or `ElementList`s, correct? How do I do this is a OO / Design Pattern way?  Do I need to re-design Element or have it implement various Interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would have to build a common interface and apply it to both classes, so you will have a base interface for both, with the needed methods and properties for using it trough the `ElementList` class and specialized interfaces for each element if needed, if not, you can implement the interfaces directly in the classes, as you did and abstract only the common interface.